# Append div to specific element

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, append

I am trying to show a message below a list-group-item when a icon is clicked. This is the code i have to show my list

```
<ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item">Feed dog <span class="edit glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="1"></span></li>
<li class="list-group-item">Email work <span class="edit glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="2"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Icon click is detected with this code

```
 $("li").on("click", ".edit", function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
     //do something
 })
```

The code I want to use is below but i dont know how to select the right element

```
$(".list-group data1").append("<li id=\"detailsitem\" class=\"list-group-item list-group-item-info\">To be appended</li>");
```

So if id = 1 then show below first li, if id = 2 show below second etc.

How can i make sure that the message is inserted below the correct li?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to do once an icon is clicked. Please give us a sample of the end result for a given click.

Comment: For your case, you should use sub list or one `div` for the selected parent list item, append the prepared markup to selected `li.list-group-item`.

Comment: once the icon is clicked the html should be appended below the appropriate li (see above)

Comment: Pretty sure you'd want to target it with `$('.list-group > span[data-id=id]').append(...`, where id is the value you obtain in your initial bit of jQuery. The way you're trying to target it won't work because data1 will cause it to look for an element called data1.

Comment: i know thats the example, because i have no clue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can i make sure that the message is inserted below the correct li?
the clicked li and where you want to post the result must have the same id, see the following example, add id field to li for example:

```
  <li class="list-group-item" id="1">Feed dog <span class="edit glyphicon glyphicon-edit"


   id="1">   

   </span></li>

  <script>
  $('.list-group-item').click(function(){


  var id=$(this).attr(id);  // get the id of the clicked div
 $('.box#'+id).append('whatever');</script>  // append whatever you want to the div with same id as the  clicked div
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$('.edit').click(function(){

        $(this).parent().after('<li id=\"detailsitem\" class=\"list-group-item list-group-item-info\">To be appended</li>')

});
```

Comment: the each function is not necessary in you example ;)

Comment: i can't tell, cause i don't know what the op really wants^^